# Postgresql function has unsupported return

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I'm very new in work with data base, and this is my first time with triggers and functions. I have two tables:
main table "orders"

```
 id | order_status_id | tracking_code
----+-----------------+---------------
 12 |               2 | 123456
  9 |               2 |
  6 |               2 |
  7 |               2 |
 10 |               2 |
  8 |               2 |
 11 |               2 |
```

and another one "order_statuses"

```
 id |   status
----+-------------
  1 | QUEUE
  2 | IN_PROGRESS
  3 | IN_DELIVERY
  4 | DELIVERED
  5 | CANCELED
  6 | RETURNED
```

I want to change value in column **order_status_id** automatically (from 2 to 3) when I change the value in column **tracking_code** (default value is null).
I wrote trigger and function:

```
CREATE TRIGGER change_status
    BEFORE UPDATE
    OF tracking_code
    ON orders
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_status();
```

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_status() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
    DECLARE
        passed bigint;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO passed FROM order_statuses WHERE status = IN_DELIVERY;
    NEW.order_status_id = passed;
    return NEW;
END;
$$;
```

but when I try to run this code, I get error:

```
[2020-09-07 15:22:53] [42804] ERROR: function "update_status" in FROM has unsupported return type trigger
[2020-09-07 15:22:53] Где: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 5 at OPEN
```

I tried to implement a lot of answers for the same question from stack overflow, but nothing helps.
can someone tell me what I do wrong and if is my code "good" in general?!

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger definition is OK, except for one thing; [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) says:

> `FOR EACH ROW`
> `FOR EACH STATEMENT`
>
> This specifies whether the trigger function should be fired once for every row affected by the trigger event, or just once per SQL statement. If neither is specified, `FOR EACH STATEMENT` is the default.

So you probably want to specify `FOR EACH ROW`.

The error message, however, has a different cause:

There is a `DO` statement somewhere in your code (“inline_code_block”) that calls `update_status` directly. That doesn't work. You can use trigger functions only in trigger definitions.